# R matlab package: why is repmat inconsistent?

Tags: r, matlab, package

I have got a question regarding the matlab package for R. Here's what I get

```
library(matlab)
a = matrix(1:4,2,2)
repmat(a,3,1)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    1    2
[4,]    3    4
[5,]    1    2
[6,]    3    4
```

this is what I expect. replicate a three times along the first dimension. but

```
b = matrix(1:6,2,3)
b
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

repmat(b,3,1)
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    1    2
[5,]    3    4
[6,]    5    6
[7,]    1    2
[8,]    3    4
[9,]    5    6
```

this is not consistent. I want a 6 by 3 matrix as the one obtained by

```
rbind(b,rbind(b,b))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    1    3    5
[4,]    2    4    6
[5,]    1    3    5
[6,]    2    4    6
```

Comment: but doesn't `a = matrix(1:4,2,2)` give you the equivalent of `[1 3; 2 4]`, so the function is consistent. It's just transposing first :/ so to solve it, transpose `a` and `b` inside that call to `repmat`

Comment: the inconsistency is that in case 1 the matrix is replicate along dimension 1, 3 times. in case 2 this is clearly not happening. i don't even know how to interpret case 2.

Comment: @FlorianOswald In both cases it looks like it transposes the matrix and then stacks it a few times...

Comment: They are consistent, write out matrix `a` the way you have matrix `b` and you'll see that it is not just replicating it nicely down the rows but it is first transposing, which is what's happening in the second case as well. In both cases it's exactly equivalent to going `repmat(x', 3, 1)` in Matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just appears to be transposing the matrix before doing the stacking.  You could just transpose your matrix before sending it into `repmat`

```
> repmat(t(b), 3, 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    1    3    5
[4,]    2    4    6
[5,]    1    3    5
[6,]    2    4    6
```

Comment: ha there you go. thanks for that. Is it just me or is this counterintuitive?

Comment: I don't use matlab so I don't know how it does things.  I'm guessing this isn't the behavior you were expecting though?

Comment: erm, wasn't expecting that at all. I just don't understand why as a user I should have to transpose the matrix first. I want to replicate `b`, not `t(b)`.

Comment: My *guess* is for the case when you throw in a vector (`repmat(1:4, 3, 1)` ) that the author wanted the vector to run across the row instead of down a column by default?

Comment: mmh yeah that could be. still, given that it's called repMAT, ie. replicate a matrix (=an object with a dim attribute), I can't see why that's necessary. I mean, what's wrong with `function(X,m,n){
mx = dim(X)[1];
nx = dim(X)[2];
matrix(t(matrix(X,mx,nx*n)),mx*m,nx*n,byrow=T)
}`

Comment: @FlorianOswald You're asking the wrong person.  Although if you're interested in implementing your own version you might want to look into the `kronecker` function

Comment: looks like a bug in the package. fwiw `repmat` in MATLAB is implemented as regular M-file, so you could `edit repmat` and look at the source code if you want to port it to R